# sound from engine!

Tags: hyundai, i20

Hers, hissing or sucking sound when only engine is off.
But no sound when on.

The marked hose is pull out. Now, engine is off. No hissing sound anymore.

Also, the end of the hose is closed and when engine running, I can feel a sucking feeling from this end hose. Really worried about this.
Pictures attached.[image][image]

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem, you say there's a sucking sound when the engine is off, is that constant, before you run the engine or after? How long does it last? What is the make, model and year of the car?

Comment: Yes, engine is started and off. At this time, the sound is coming as soon as engine is off. It doesn't come when engine is running, idle. It lasts for about 5 seconds only. This happens just 3 days ago only. It's Hyundai i20 1.2 petrol 2011.

Comment: Loosen the oil fill cap, does it still do it?

Comment: Yes, the sound still comes even when the cap is fully open. It only goes away when the above marked hose is disconnected. Is the pcv valve defunct??? And, I think the pcv hose is ok since I got a pull or suck when block by thumb during engine running.